# Show axes and plots as they are created during GUIDE GUI initialization

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, matlab-guide

I have a Matlab gui created in GUIDE. When I click a button in `gui_A`, it opens a new figure window for `gui_B` (different fig and m files for both). The plot takes a long time to generate each item on it, so I want to plot each item as soon as it is ready. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get the window to render FIRST, and THEN plot things on it. I've tried using `pause(1)` and `drawnow` but neither have the desired effect. Here's some sample code for what I'm doing:

in `gui_A`

```
function open_gui_b_btn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    gui_B(handles.var1, handles.var2);
```

in `gui_B`

```
function gui_B_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    handles.output = hObject;
    handles.var1 = varargin{1};
    handles.var2 = varargin{2};
    % set some variables here
    % plot something on an axis

    % Try to render on screen
    % drawnow % doesn't work
    % pause(1) % doesn't work

    % plot the rest of the things
    plot_things(handles)

function plot_things(handles)
    for i = 1:length(handles.something)
        % computationally expensive process
        plot(handles.axis1, handles.var1b, handles.var2b);
    end
```

Obviously I would like for the window of `gui_B` to render on the screen and then have the plot things function plot all the things as soon as they are ready so the user can watch the progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that when loading the GUI, GUIDE will (by default) set the `Visible` property of the figure to `'off'` so that a potentially incomplete GUI won't be shown to the user. It will toggle the `Visible` property back to `'on'` after all initialization is complete. You can alter this behavior by manually settings the `Visible` property to `'on'` within your `OpeningFcn`

```
function gui_B_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
    handles.output = hObject;
    handles.var1 = varargin{1};
    handles.var2 = varargin{2};

    % Make sure the figure is visible
    set(hObject, 'Visible', 'on')
    drawnow
```

Or you can initialize your GUI by providing the `Visible` property in the function call

```
gui_B('Visible', 'on')
```

After doing that, you'll also want to add explicit `drawnow` commands after each plot command to cause the graphics to be rendered right away.

```
function plot_things(handles)
    for i = 1:length(handles.something)
        % computationally expensive process
        plot(handles.axis1, handles.var1b, handles.var2b);

        % Draw each plot as it's available
        drawnow
    end
```

Comment: That was it. Thank you. Does the Visible property get set explicitly in another function after the OpeningFcn runs?

Comment: @toshiomagic Yes, the `guimain_fcn` function actually modifies this visibility  automatically, but the modifications shown above have no impact other than  adding the desired behavior.

Comment: @toshiomagic Updated with a little more information and some alternatives.

Comment: Funny you added the drawnow command in plot_things. I literally did that just before I came back here to refresh the page and see it.